# How to escape multiple parameters with "-with-rtsopts"

Tags: haskell-stack

Using `stack`, you can specify `-with-rtsopts` in `package.yaml` as follows

```
ghc-options:
- -with-rtsopts=-N
```

However, it is unclear how to represent several rtsopts at once.  In this example I've put double quotes around them

```
ghc-options:
- -with-rtsopts="-N -I0 -qg"
```

... but this does not work ...

```
Preprocessing library for uke-0.1.0.0..
Building library for uke-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing executable 'uke-exe' for uke-0.1.0.0..
Building executable 'uke-exe' for uke-0.1.0.0..
ghc: unrecognised flag: -qg"
```

What is the proper way to escape multiple `-with-rtsopts` values in `package.yaml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if you double quote the whole expression:

```
ghc-options:
- '"-with-rtsopts=-N -I0 -qg"'
```

Comment: It seems you don't need the outer single quotes, this works `ghc-options: -O2 -threaded -eventlog "-with-rtsopts=-N -s"`